# Filter common values between text files

Tags: perl

I'm a beginner at perl and I'm trying to filter a large text file with 1 column of ID names, each a few characters long and unique, e.g.:

```
Aghm
Tbc2
Popc
Ltr1
Iubr
Osv5
```

and filter this list against a second text file with some of the same ID names, e.g.:

```
Popc
Iubr
Trv7
Ybd8
```

I only want to find the common ID names and print into a new text file. In the example above I want to generate the list:

```
Popc
Iubr
```

How can I do it using perl script?

Comment: @Zaid: If the OP is a beginner, your answer is a bit dry... :p

Comment: @Seki : What's important is to see that an effort has been made.

Answer (score 1):

To put you on a path, you seem to make a Perl *filter*.

You could try by opening the first file, looping on the *diamond operator* (that is `<>`) and writing selected lines to the second file.

You should try to get a copy of the Perl Cookbook, the [chapter 07](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch07_08.htm) is dealing of such case.

Answer (score 1):

Having the id file `ids.txt`, filter file `filter_ids.txt` this would write the desired result to `filtered_ids.txt`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $rh, '<', 'filter_ids.txt' or die "$!\n";

my %filter = map {$_ => 1} <$rh>;

open $rh, '<', 'ids.txt' or die "$!\n";
open my $wh, '>', 'filtered_ids.txt' or die "$!\n";

map {print $wh $_} grep $filter{$_}, <$rh>;

close $wh;
```

Personally I'd rather do this with `grep`:

```
grep -f filter_ids.txt ids.txt > filtered_ids.txt
```

Result in either case:

```
flesk@flesk:~$ more filtered_ids.txt 
Popc
Iubr
```

Comment: Thanks I was using awk function, something like `awk -F"," 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next} ($1 in a)' filter_ids.txt ids.txt` but did not work - my text file may be too big. Your suggestion worked a treat!

Comment: I can't imagine that being the case. Did you try `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]' filter_ids.txt ids.txt > filtered_ids.txt`?

Comment: The awk command now works. The filter_ids text file was not tab-delimited text although I was sure I format it this way initially - it would not allow awk to produce a result, but works fine now with all suggestions above. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1153710: My pleasure. Might I suggest accepting the answer?